# hide message elements if value =default... in jquery

Tags: jquery

The following code is the one that sends the mmessage...... i want to have a check that
when a user doenst select any filter and leave the default filter "SELECT" those blocks wont sent to the user in their message......thx in advance for your time

```
$('#sendMessageButton').click(function(){
   $('#result').removeClass("alert-message error");
   $('#result').html('');
   $('#sendMessageButton').attr('value','Sending...');
   $('#sendMessageButton').addClass('disabled');

   if($('#messageType').val() == 'contactme'){
      $('#content').val(encodeURIComponent('<div id ="ask-a-question-message" style="padding:15px;"><div style="color:#63872C;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:20px;">Hey, I have a question for you!</div><div style="background-color:#F3F3F3;padding:7px;"><div style="font-style:italic;margin-bottom:5px;">Some information for my trip</div><div style="font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;color:#777;margin-top:10px;">Date arriving in ${user.city.label}</div><div>'+$('#travel-date').val()+'</div><div style="font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;color:#777;margin-top:10px;">Traveler type</div><div>'+$('#travel-type').val()+'</div><div style="font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;color:#777;margin-top:10px;">Budget</div><div>'+$('#budget-type').val()+'</div></div><div style="padding:7px;"><div style="font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;color:#777;margin-top:10px;"">Question</div><div>'+$('#preselected-question').val()+'</div><div>'+$('#freeform-question').val()+'</div></div></div>'));
   }

 $.post(sendMessage({recipientId:$('#recipientId').val(),messageType:$('#messageType').val(),itemId:$('#itemId').val(),content:$('#content').val().replace(new RegExp('\n','g'), '<br />')}), function(data) {
    if(!(data.data && data.data.error)){
       $('#sendMessageButton').removeClass('btn-primary');
       $('#sendMessageButton').addClass('success');
       $('#sendMessageButton').attr('value','Message sent');

       setTimeout(function() {
          $('#new-message-modal').modal('hide');
       }, 1000);

       setTimeout(function() {
          $('#sendMessageButton').removeClass('disabled');
          $('#sendMessageButton').attr('value','Send');
       }, 1500);


    }

    else{
       $('#result').addClass("alert-message error");
       $('#result').html(data.data.error);
    }
 })
})
//else
```

Comment: thats one hell of a encodeURIComponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first option has an empty value:

```
if( $('select#Filter').find('option:selected').val().length===0 ){ /* ... */ }
```

Or if you want to test on text (which is a bit slower, but hardly noticable:)

```
if( $('select#Filter').find('option:selected').text()=='SELECT' ){ /* ... */ }
```

Comment: This is not difficult to find on google, just search for something `how to check if selectlist option is selected`